# Windows Azure and multiple storage accounts

Tags: azure, multi-tenant

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 Azure application that I am trying to switch from being single tenant to multi-tenant. I have been reviewing many blogs and posts and questions here on Stack Overflow, but am still trying to wrap my head around the specifics of what's right for this particular app.

Currently the application stores some information in a SQL Azure database, as well as some other info in an Azure Storage Account. I'm considering writing the tenant provisioning code to simply create a new database for a new tenant, along with a new azure storage account. This brings me to the following question:

How will I go about testing this approach locally? As far as I can tell, the local Azure Storage Emulator only has 1 storage account. I'm not sure if I'm able to create others locally. How will I be able to test this locally? Or will it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many aspects to consider with multitenancy, one of which is data architecture. You also have billing, performance, security and so forth.

Regarding data architecture, let's first explore SQL storage. You have the following options available to you: add a CustomerID (or other identifyer) that your code will use to filter records, use different schema containers for different customers (each customer has its own copy of all the database objects owned by a dedicated schema in a database), linear sharding (in which each customer has its own database) and Federation (a feature of SQL Azure that offers progressive sharding based on performance and scalability needs). All these options are valid, but have different implications on performance, scalability, security, maintenance (such as backups), cost and of course database design. I couldn't tell you which one to choose based on the information you provided; some models are easier to implement than others if you already have a code base. Generally speaking a linear shard is the simplest model and provides strong customer isolation, but perhaps the most expensive of all. A schema-based separation is not too hard, but requires a good handle on security requirements and can introduce cross-customer performance issues because this approach is not shared-nothing (for customers on the same database). Finally Federations requires the use of a customer identifyer and has a few limitations; however this technology gives you more control over performance distribution and long-term scalability (because like a linear shard, Federation uses a shared-nothing architecture).

Regarding storage accounts, using different storage accounts per customer is definitively the way to go. The primary issue you will face if you don't use separate storage accounts is performance limitations, such as the maximum number of transactions per second that can be executed using a single storage account. As you are pointing out however, testing locally may be a problem; however consider this: the local emulator does not offer 100% parity with an Azure Storage Account (some functions are not supported in the emulator). So I would only use the local emulator for initial development and troubleshooting. Any serious testing, including multitenant testing, should be done using real storage accounts. This is the only way you can fully test an application.

Comment: Thank you! This concisely sums up all of the options I have been learning about and looking into while tackling this project. I noticed you are a consultant who specializes in this exact area of technology, would you be interested in arranging a deal where I pay you or someone from your team to help me build a really basic skeleton multi-tenant app to help me understand all of the different components to the main multi-tenant issues of provisioning/auth/metering/scaling/billing? Then I can turn around and apply the same theories to my client's app! Let me know if this is of interest to you :)

Comment: If you're interested, email me at my name (john)  at johnarnold.ca

Comment: Hi John - glad I could help. Regarding the multitenant framework, I already developed one! You can find it here: https://scale.bluesyntax.net. It's still in Beta, but it provides a good model for linear and schema separation sharding. Additional details about the API provided and more can be found here: https://scale.bluesyntax.net/About.aspx - I will contact you separately to see if this is of interest to you or if you are looking for something more customized.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider not creating separate databases, but instead creating different object namespaces within a single SQL database.  Each tenant can have their own set of tables.

Depending on how you are using storage, you can create separate storage containers or message queues per client.

Given these constraints you should be able to test locally with the storage emulator and local SQL instance.

Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have considered the alternatives of having clients data in a shared database, but there are a few reasons why we are leaning towards each customer having a db.. namely to keep the data physically separate for scalability and maintenance/backups. We recognize there is a larger cost in doing so.